# How Java SplashScreen works?

Tags: java, swing, splash-screen

I need to implement a SplashScreen in java, and i'm currently learning from [How to Create a Splash Screen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) but there is paragraph that says

> Fortunately, Java™ SE 6 provides a solution that allows the application to 
>   display the splash screen much earlier, even before the virtual machine starts.
>   A Java application launcher is able to decode an image and display it in a 
>   simple non-decorated window.

How is possible that java run the SplashScreen even if virtual machine starts if SplashScreen is a java class?

Comment: later in the article - command line option; jar file manifest.

Comment: Read the section 'How to Use a JAR File to Display Splash Screen'. I guess just defining it in the manifest file is enough.

Comment: Yeah, but I mean, how technically java display the splash screen even if the JVM doesn't start?

Comment: Technically, the splash screen is an "image".  Presumably, before the JVM is loaded, the image is loaded and displayed in a native window using native code.  The intent is to put something one the screen before the JVM is initialised, as this might take time before the JVM is available and your classes are loaded

Comment: The JVM is a C++ program. Using this option, it displays the splash screen while the JVM is being initialized, instead of having to wait until the JVM has been fully initialized before it can display it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you define the splash screen in your jar MANIFEST-file, it is loaded and displayed with native code before the Java VM is started. No need to load a class in that case. Later, you can get the SplashScreen instance to edit and/or close it.

Manifest entry:

```
SplashScreen-Image: images/splash.gif
```

Or command line option:

```
-splash:images/nnn.gif
```

> Java Platform, Standard Edition (Java SE, formerly known as J2SE)
>   version 6, provides a solution that allows the application to show the
>   splash screen much earlier, even before the virtual machine starts.
>   **Now, a Java application launcher is able to decode an image and
>   display it in a simple nondecorated window.**

Source:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/splashscreen-135938.html